# Disable back button in Android doesn't work

Tags: android, back-button

I'm programming an Android app API 11 and I used it in a TabActivity:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
}
```

But the back button still works, why? Do I have todo something diferent in a TabActivity?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, easy answer, I had to put it into the child activities of each tab.